# How to use passport with next.js API?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, next.js

I'm trying to use [passport-spotify](https://github.com/jmperez/passport-spotify) with next.js's pages/api (the one where you use `export default (req, res)...`), but I can't get it to redirect to Spotify's authorization page. This is my code for `pages/api/spotify.js`:

```
var passport = require('passport');
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: clientid,
      clientSecret: clientsecret,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/spotify/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({ spotifyId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);

export default (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('spotify', {
        scope: ['user-read-email', 'user-read-private'],
        showDialog: true
      }),
    res.end()
}
```

I've tried using express to test it, and it works there. Here's my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8000
var passport = require('passport');
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: clientid,
      clientSecret: clientsecret,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({ spotifyId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      });
    }
  )
);
app.get(
    '/auth/spotify',
    passport.authenticate('spotify', {
      scope: ['user-top-read'],
      showDialog: true
    }),
    function(req, res) {
      // The request will be redirected to spotify for authentication, so this
      // function will not be called.
    }
  );

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Is there a way to have Next.js work with Passport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it! I used [next-connect](https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect). Here's an example Spotify authentication request with passport-spotify and next.js:

```
// pages/api/spotify.js
import nc from 'next-connect';
var passport = require('passport');
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;

passport.use(
  new SpotifyStrategy(
    {
      clientID: clientid,
      clientSecret: clientsecret,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate({ spotifyId: profile.id }, function(err, user) {
        return done(err, user);
      })
    }
  ))

const handler = nc()
  .get(passport.authenticate('spotify', {
    scope: ['user-top-read']
  }), (req, res) => {
  })

export default handler;
```